# Does $HK = G$ imply that $KH = G$ when $H,K$ aren't subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ and $K$ be two "subsets" of $G$ such that $HK = G$. Does that imply that $KH = G$?

Since $H$ and $K$ are not subgroups we cannot use the formula $o(HK) = \frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$.

I believe this is false and I am looking for counterexamples.

Thank you.

Comment: Conjugation perhaps?

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ are not subgroups but are closed under inverses, then it's true. So you need one of them to fail to be closed under inverses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully I didn't make any stupid mistake :)

Let $G=S_3$ and 
$$H= \{ e, (1,2) \} \\
K=\{ e, (1,3), (1,2,3) \}$$

Then 
$$HK= S_3$$
but
$$(1,3)(1,2)=(1,2,3)=(1,2,3)e$$
showing that $KH$ can have at most 5 distinct elements.

Comment: Thank you N.S.  This example is simple and nice.